# React onclick listener doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onclicklistener

Simple thing, I'm supposed to make a counter app that increments/decrcements/resets a counter if I click on the corresponding button (up/down/reset).

I'm new to React but know some js.

I get this as error message

```
Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
    in button (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
```

```
<script type=text/babel>
    class App extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {count: 0} // init count
        }
        
        render() {
            return <div className="counter">
                <div className="title">Counter</div>
                <div className="number">{this.state.count}</div>
                <div className="buttons">
                    <button onClick='incrementCounter()'>Up</button>
                    <button onClick='decrementCounter()'>Down</button>
                    <button onClick='resetCounter()'>Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        // why does this not work?
        incrementCounter(){
            this.setState( state => ({ count: this.state.count + 1 }) )
        }

        decrementCounter(){
            this.setState( state => ({ count: this.state.count - 1 }) )
        }

        resetCounter(){
            this.setState( state => ({ count: 0 }) )
        }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onClick='incrementCounter()'` needs to be `onClick={this.incrementCounter}`, and similar for the other onClick's

Comment: (you almost certainly need to [bind it in the constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) as well, since you're using class components. Actually that whole page starts with a perfect explanation of exactly what's wrong with your code - the part about binding is a bit further down.)